# ImportError: cannot import name 'types'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to deploy my telegram bot in heroku i get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'types'
```

my requirements.txt

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
requests==2.7.0
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.6.6
Werkzeug==0.14.1
requests==2.7.0
```

my imports

```
import telebot
import os
from telebot import types
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you got a file in your script directory called `telebot.py`? What is the output of `print(telebot.__file__)`?

Comment: There's an official module named types, please don't name your own stuff after official stuff.

Comment: @Jared SmithL It looks like the author(s) of telebot named a module `types`, not the OP. Secondly, it's OK to name a module the same as a built-in (`types` isn't a key-word),

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there are issues on GitHub with this same question. This is what you could try

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

After successful installation of this library, you can move to writing something like this:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
```

Also, this [documentation](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) here should give you an idea of how to accomplish whatever your trying to do

Good Luck!